# htaccess file to tidy up urls causes 500 server error if a trailing slash is added to the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server-error

Hi please can anyone help,

I've written an htaccess file to tidy up my urls & remove the .php.  It all seems to work well but if a trailing slash is added onto a url now the .php has gone I get a 500 server error.  What I really want to happen is if a trailing slash is added then it's handled smoothly and redirected to the no trailing slash option.  This seems to work on the homepage, but not on any other page.

My website is www.bekcruddace.co.uk & the htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirects example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bekcruddace.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.bekcruddace\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Please could anyone offer any pointers?

I should also mention that the news sections is a separate plugin that runs independently so the url is slightly different & isn't relevant to my question.

Thank you.

Comment: which request url you got the 500 server error?

Comment: Hi, it's all pages return a 500 server error if you add a trailing slash except the shop, news and homepage.

Answer (score 0):

If you request  **/file/** your rule rewrites it to an invalid location **/file/.php** . That is why your server is producing a 500 error.

You need to make the traling slash optional in your pattern so that the slash is excluded from the capture group:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer but I've already something similar.  I've replaced RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php with RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php as you suggested and still have the same problem - a 500 server error when a trailing slash is added to a url...?